# Is it okay to switch the company if boss humiliates you?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, resignation, pressure

I dont know it is a good forum to ask. But i really need your help guys. There are many problems i am facing.

1. First the deadlines of project delivery.
2. Second the constant pressure from the boss.
3. Boss humiliates about working infront of others.

In all of these situations what to do? If he is mocking me and disrespecting me infront of others. what to do in this situation ? Is it good to reply him back in same tone ?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace -- there's a lot packed into these three areas, and it's hard to give a good answer without more details. This forum deals with questions that can be given a more-or-less objective answer, so it's better if you can narrow this down to a more specific question. "What should I do?" is not really something we can answer.

Comment: If you mean the boss is setting unrealistic deadlines, see [Dealing with unrealistic deadlines](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49927/dealing-with-unrealistic-deadlines).

Comment: @mcknz ok i am editing my question

Comment: What do you mean by "constant pressure"?

Comment: Regarding your boss publicly humiliating you, see [How can I deal with an abusive manager who publicly belittles me?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13632/how-can-i-deal-with-an-abusive-manager-who-publicly-belittles-me)

Comment: Your new phrasing isn't really better. It's okay to switch companies for whatever reason you want, we can't make that decision for you though. I personally think asking "what should I do" is fine here (many posts ask a similar question, like the above post which asks "how can I deal with...") - the *usual* problem with "what should I do" is when the question asks us to make a decision for you (like whether you should quit or not). See also [this Meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2693#2695). The main problem is there isn't enough details here.

Comment: @Dukeling Constant pressure means the work pressure. To do the work on time. What more details i have to give?

Comment: @Dukeling people have given the advice and i am here to take a advice in this particular situation. why people cant say say to quit? i have seen other posts in which they have given a straight to the point opinion to quit or not to quit.

Comment: In those cases, there's enough detail given where it's easy to make that determination, typically if whats being described is an obviously toxic environment that extends beyond one bad boss. Are you being specifically targeted? Have you tried to talk to your boss or is he so unreasonable that he doesn't allow this window to be open? Have you discussed this with anyone else?

Comment: He is unpredictable on deadlines he is always angry. He always push everyone for a small and not-in-time deadlines. Some survives some not. No we cant talk because if we talk he will mock about this talk again infront of everyone taunting about the problems i have with him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it okay to switch the company if boss humiliates you?

It's ok to switch companies for any reason whatsoever so long as you are not breaching a contract.